# Adobe Dreamweaver CC Won't Open on Mavericks

Tags: adobe, dreamweaver, osx-mavericks, creative-cloud

No matter what I do, Dreamweaver just opens in the dock for 1 second and closes.  There is no output in the console.

I followed this thread http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1325523 and several others.  I installed a couple versions of Java and reinstalled Dreamweaver but nothing works so far.

What's the deal?  All of the other CC applications have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just described what use to happen to me with a different app that needed java. I know you said you installed a different java version, but did you remove it before reinstalling it? Oh and are you running os x 10.9.2? Most of the time its good to stay update to date. Using the java version 21 or 25 fixed my problem hopefully this helps.

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml

Comment: Thanks. I did uninstall Java, but I think I am on 10.9.1.  I will check it out, give it a shot when I get home, and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what fixed it for me.

On my mac with yosemite there was a permissions problem that was stopping DW and other CC apps from launching

In Terminal I typed cd /Users/yourusername/Library/Application support

Then I typed ls -la Adobe/ to see the permissions of the contents of the Adobe folder

In the folder /Users/yourusername/Library/Application Suppport/Adobe some of the sub-folders had the owner as root:wheel and not yourusername:staff

I then typed chown -R yourusername:staff Adobe/

This makes yourusername:staff the owner of the sub-folders

Now all of the CC software launches.